# dc.js - Hide the div container till the svg is created

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, dc.js

I've created a series of the chart using `dc.js`. The visualization is of huge records about 1M. When I open it in the browser. At the beginning I only get the `div` with colors what I've given. I wanted to hide those div which is container in a `div.container`.

Can any one suggest me a best way on hiding the div until the svg is created?

Help will be very much pleased.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You could set its opacity to 0 and then to 1 once the SVG is there.

Comment: I can even hide the div and unhide the div when the SVG is created. Problem is I don't have any idea on how will I be getting the time when the svg is created. Can you help me on how can i get to know when the SVG is created?

Comment: Does it work if you run the code to to show the `div` after all the code to set up the SVG?

Comment: I didn't write any code actually. I only written code to draw the chart using `dc.js`. How it loads is. The div on which I'm creating the SVG. I've created another inside of it for the header of the chart. At the beginning when i load the page. Only that header div is visible. And after 10-15 seconds. The SVG chart appears. I wanted to hide that div until i get the chart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the listeners might be what you're looking for, e.g. `postRedraw` or `postRender`.

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#listeners

Note you can also get dc.js to render into a div that is not on-screen  and then reparent it.  Just supply the div element itself instead of a selector for the parent parameter of the constructor.